# Accessing to Heart Service in BLE device returns null

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to read the heart rate from a BLE device (It's a smartwatch and the model is CURREN R5 Pro), but when I get the Heart Rate Service, it returns null.

This is the code:

```
class Constants {
    final static UUID HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID = convertFromInteger(0x180D);
    final static UUID HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT_UUID = convertFromInteger(0x2A37);
    final static UUID HEART_RATE_CONTROL_POINT_UUID = convertFromInteger(0x2A39);
    final static UUID CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID = convertFromInteger(0x2902);

    private static UUID convertFromInteger(int i) {
        final long MSB = 0x0000000000001000L;
        final long LSB = 0x800000805f9b34fbL;
        long value = i & 0xFFFFFFFF;
        return new UUID(MSB | (value << 32), LSB);
    }
}


private final BluetoothGattCallback bluetoothGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
        }
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            //getCharacteristic(HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT_UUID) returns null
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = gatt.getService(HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID)
                    .getCharacteristic(HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT_UUID);
            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);

            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = gatt.getService(HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID)
                .getCharacteristic(HEART_RATE_CONTROL_POINT_UUID);
        characteristic.setValue(DATA_STREAMING_COMMAND);
        gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if (HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT_UUID.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            Log.d(TAG, "HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT_UUID");
            //PROCESS DATA
        }
        if (HEART_RATE_CONTROL_POINT_UUID.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            Log.d(TAG, "HEART_RATE_CONTROL_POINT_UUID");
            //PROCESS DATA
        }
    }
};
```

However, the only app that is able to read the heart rate from the device is [Wearfit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakeup.smartband). Other applications are not able to read the heart rate from this device.

The services that I'm able to get are these:

- 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
- 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
- 6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e
- 00001530-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
- 0000fee7-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

Has anyone experienced this situation? Is there anything wrong with my code? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the UUID. Try to read the characteristic for the heart rate  with the nordic app nrf connect. The app will display you all supported services/characteristics from your smartwatch.

Comment: Same result. I get the same services and characteristics than before. Only the Wearfit app is able to connect with the device and read the heart measurement. I tried to decompile its apk and inspect the code, but it's been obfuscated.

Comment: Crazy. Maybe you had to switch on the heart rate sensor with another service...just a guess. Please tell me if you find a solution

Comment: I've been trying to find a solution for this problem for almost 2 days. I'm about to give up. I emailed the Wearfit's developers, but I haven't received any response. I also tried to find documentation about the device, but I found nothing.

Comment: The heart rate sensor in your watch works with light. Maybe you had to switch on a LED to get a valid value from the sensor. Are there any writable characteristics you could see in the nordic app?

Comment: You can see all the services and characteristics here https://imgur.com/a/l7zYfco

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution to your problem ? I have the same issue with wearfit band.

Comment: I ended up using a Xiaomi Mi Band 2 and it worked like a charm, but I didn´t find a solution. BLE devices are weird.